# SAS print variable on one line

Tags: printing, sas

I have google the whole universe but cannot find out this.
Given data set A:

```
a b
1 2
3 4
1 2
```

I want to print this to result in this way:

```
a 1 3 1
b 2 4 2
```

Also print each variable, name first then content on one line to result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for for proc transpose:

```
proc transpose data = A out = A_transpose;
var a b;
run;
```

Then you can print this with proc print:

```
proc print data = A_transpose;
run;
```